# Conditional actions depending on error output

Tags: bash, if-statement, error-handling, udisks

Is there a way to perform an if statement based on the error output of a command?

For example, I want to use `udisksctl` in a script which mounts a USB drive and then perform some action on the drive contents.

1. The drive is not mounted: it should mount it and then perform the
   action.
2. The drive is absent: it should throw an error message and exit;
3. The drive is already mounted, it should perform the action;

Running `udisksctl` can have three results in this scenario:

In case 1), it runs successfully.

In the other two cases it returns an error, but:

- In case 2), it gives me the error: `Error looking up object for device ...`
- In case 3) it gives me the error: `Error mounting /dev/sdb1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.AlreadyMounted: Device /dev/sdb1 is already mounted at`

Is there an elegant way to make an if statement which takes different actions based on these two error messages?

Piping the error message to grep like this `udisksctl mount -b /dev/disk/by-label/CRUZER 2> >(grep -i "Error looking up object for device")` seems to make no difference in the output.

Comment: assuming the error messages are sent to stderr: `udisksctl mount -b /dev/disk/by-label/CRUZER 2>&1 | grep -i "Error looking up object for device"`; though if the objective is to run a couple different conditionals, and possibly save the error output to a log file, I'd probably capture all `udisksctl` output to a temp file and then process the temp file as needed; you may want to update the question with the code you're using to implement the conditional tests (`if/elif/else` ? `case`? using `BASH_REMATCH`?)

Comment: Beware of `udisksctl`man page warn: `Additionally, this program is not intended to be used by scripts or other
       programs - options/commands may change in incompatible ways in the future even in maintenance releases.`

Comment: When errors are generated, does udisksctl exit with a non-zero exit status?

Comment: @glennjackman In both errors, the exit code is 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Branching on the text of error messages is brittle; the text could change between versions, or you could get messages which are similar but mean different things, or the output could change to a different language depending on the user's locale. But to do what you are asking, try

```sh
if result=$(udiskctl mount -b /dev/disk/by-label/CRUZER 2>&1); then
  : success
else
  rc=$?
  case $result in
    *"Error looking up object for device"*)
      echo case 2;;
    *"Error mounting /dev/sdb"*)
      echo case 3;;
    *) echo "$0: unexpected error $result" >&2
       exit $rc
       ;;
   esac
fi
```

The `case` inside the `if` is a bit unattractive; I suppose you could refactor this to use `elif` but then you'd have to refactor the capturing of the exit code from the failed command (assuming you care what the exit code was).

You could obviously make the search strings more or less specific; I tried to keep them fairly general.

Comment: An alternate method for the same effect: `result=$(udisksctl ...); rc=$?` then use case with both the exit status and the output (insert newlines liberally): `case "$rc:$result" in (0:*) echo success ;; (1:*"Error looking up object for device"*) echo case 2 ;; ` and so on

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @markp-fuso, this is what I got:

```
udtmp=$(mktemp /tmp/$(basename "$0".XXXXXXXX))

udisksctl mount -b /dev/disk/by-label/CRUZER 2> $udtmp

 if grep -i "Error looking up object for device" $udtmp ; then
     exit
 elif grep -i "GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.AlreadyMounted" $udtmp ; then
     do something
 fi
 
 do something else
```

@LMC thank you for the heads up. I think I'll be using it anyway because `udiskctl` works well with Thunar and `mnt` much less.

Comment: The temporary file is unattractive and easy to avoid.

Comment: @tripleee Agreed, that's why I chose your answer as the solution